# How to display the data as augmented only if the user is facing towards a feature in the real world?

Tags: orientation, augmented-reality, feature-detection, object-recognition, android-augmented-reality

I am currently developing an augmented reality android application in which I would like to display the discharge data of a river along with the river name as augmented features. However, I would like to show the data augmented only if an user is facing his device camera towards the river and not in the opposite direction.

How shall I get to implement this?

I thought that there could be two ways:

1. feature detection: but I do not know if it would work as the feature here which is river is quiet dynamic.
2. something to do with the orientation of the phone with respect to the real world. However, I do not really get an idea of how I can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to implement is to use GPS based Augmented reality.So basically you are attaching feature on GPS location and when user holds camera in direction of that GPS location closed to it the detection will happen. Definitely you should not go for image based feature detection.
you may follow the links below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6djed8e4n0

http://wirebeings.com/markerless-gps-ar.html

I hope this helps.